# Can Blender Grease Pencil apply mask to png images

Tags: 2d

So when I use a blender Grease Pencil and I use the mask feature it only shows up on drawings and I can't get it to work on PNG images I have searched the internet but I can't find anything.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way with the _Grease Pencil_, I only know how to paint on the alpha channel in _Texture Paint_ mode...